# how to encode uiimageview in ios

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have a user who has a avatar, i use uiimageview to save this avatar, so how can i encode avatar ? or you can give me a suggestion, how to encode user's avatar(image).

Comment: what do you mean encode the uiimageview?

Comment: it means, i want to save user's info in document directory by encoding tec, but user's avatar can't encode

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` to convert a `UIImage` to a `NSData` which can be turned back to an `UIImage` again.

Comment: can you give me an example about save and gain image?